# Pigeon Hole Principle Problem. Least number you need to get two pairs

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

A drawer has ten blue, ten white, and ten red socks. Without looking at them you pull some socks out.  What is the least number of socks you need to pull to ensure you get TWO pairs of matching socks?

Comment: Any thoughts?  The usual thing is to try to describe the worst possible choice of socks.

Comment: The answer is 6. I'll let you figure out why.

Comment: After removing 6 socks the next (7th) sock assures us that we have at last two pairs of matching socks. I dont quite understand why this is the case

Comment: @PhysMath ...unless your socks also exhibit chirality, but then you might have more problems [mostly joking]

Comment: What about the possibility of the two pairs intersecting? If you draw red, blue, green, red, red, you have three red socks; in particular there are 3 pairs of red socks, if you double count.

Answer (score 2):

Drawing six socks ensures two pairs have been drawn.

After you pull four socks you have at least one pair.  You could have two pair already, but that is not relevant for this question.  Your configurations are ([partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $4$ into three parts)
$$  400, 310, 220, 211  \text{.}  $$
In these configurations, we are indifferent to *which* color are a certain number of socks.  "$400$" just means four of one color and none of the other two.  Let's extend these cases by up to two socks each, to see what happens.

- In the $400$ case we are already done, having two pairs of one color of sock.
- In the $310$ case, if we pull a fourth of the first color or a second of the second color, we have two matching pairs, so to avoid finishing, we must draw to $311$ with the fifth sock.  Then regardless of the color of the sixth sock, we have two matching pairs.
- In the $220$ case, we are already done.
- In the $211$ case, we finish if the fifth sock is of the second or third colors, so we proceed assuming the fifth sock is of the first color, yielding the configuration $311$.  Then as above, the sixth sock necessarily completes a second pair.

Answer (score 1):

Draw two socks that match to make a pair and put them to the side (it doesn't matter which color).

Then how many more socks can we draw without making a second pair? Three (one of each color)

After doing that, draw any one sock from the drawer and you are guaranteed to make a second pair, so the answer is $2 + 3 + 1 = 6.$

Comment: This answer feels like it is correct for the wrong reason, but the reasoning is actually solid.  +1.

Comment: @abiessu Thanks.  I guess I should point out that the parenthetical "it doesn't matter which color" in the first step is actually the reason why the whole argument works.  If we tried to generalize the argument to a larger number of pairs of socks, then we might run into issues in the first step if we can exhaust one type of sock.